# How to access the request object inside a custom logging formatter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-logging

I have setup a custom formatter to log my data into a text file in JSON format:

```
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
      super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
      log_record['timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
      log_record['level'] = record.levelname
      log_record['location'] = record.name
```

I would like to be able to automatically access my request object within this formatted since I have a "unique request identifier" that I would like to add to my logs. This way I know which log lines belong to which request.

```
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
      super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
      log_record['timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
      log_record['level'] = record.levelname
      log_record['location'] = record.name

      log_record['request_id'] = request.uuid   <--- Something like this
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to manually pass the request object to every single log line?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you describe what you want as a result? do you simply want to track user requests? how many requests? how frequent the requests?

Comment: Try using `record.request.uuid` That's how it's set up in Django's own Admin Email Handler (Located in `utils\log.py` *line 93*) but the attribute might not be there and then it must be manually attached in the logger call with the `extra` argument

Comment: @Nealium yea i tested that already bu9t record.request doesn't exist. for that to work you need to pass it through the extra params every time you log something which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: oof. Yeah Ik it sucks and you've got to pass it 2-3 functions deep- not fun!

Comment: Exactly! If you are interested I found this little module that might do the trick. Havent tested it yet. Im surprised how this doesn't come by default since knowing which log line belongs to which requests seems to be a must when debugging issues in production.
https://github.com/dabapps/django-log-request-id

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use middleware to attach the request to the thread context, and then access it in your formatter through threadlocals:
class RequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        self.process_response(request, response)
        return response

    def process_request(self, request):
        Thread.currentThread().request = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(Thread.currentThread(), 'request'):
            del Thread.currentThread().request
        return response

Then in your formatter:
threadlocals.request.uuid

Note that this uses thread-local storage, so this will only work correctly if your Django application uses threading and not multiple processes.
Alternatively, you can pass the request explicitly as an extra parameter to the logger:
logger.info('message', extra={'request': request})

and then access that in your formatter as message_dict['request']. This will work across processes as well.
```